# Return multiple values by reading multiple columns and change based on the column selection

Tags: excel-formula

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheet]

Hello,

I am trying to get all the users with 'Yes' status from the data for 'A qualified' and in my results, the users list should change based on the selection. If selected 'B qualified' the Yes people under B qualified column should display.

Created a drop down for A qualified, B qualified and C qualified.  I was able to get results for one column because I selected the data range. Having trouble with linking column headings and reading the results based on the headings. Please help

Comment: Pl share the logic used in the cells to display the derived values (e.g. how you are populating the dropdown of ["A qualified","B...","C..."] and how you are populating the values underneath in the cells below this dropdown presently. Then, people can look at it and give you updated one as the answer.

Comment: I am using Data validation - crate list and selecting range to create a dropdown. I can also use Combo box to create a drop down and the list of values will be linked to one cell. Advantage of Combo box is, it is searchable and is useful when dealing large set of data for drop down list

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this, I'll give you just the, IMHO, easiest and most understandable (to audit and for others that would look at your spreadsheet).

On a separate part of your workbook (can be visible next to your data on the same worksheet, or you can put this on a separate worksheet, and hide this if you want), you put a list (let's call it quali-matrix) of A qualified, B qualified, ..., and next to it, you put the cell range of the actual data, or the name of the range if you prefer working with named ranges. Then you choose a cell on that worksheet (let's say `SheetX!A1`) where you put the lookup results (lookup value is what's chosen in the drop down box and lookup range is quali-matrix).

So the above will give you a cell where the actual lookup range is that you will use in the big formula (the one that I gave you on SU) with the `INDIRECT` function. So the formula becomes:
`{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9,SMALL(IF(INDIRECT(SheetX!$A$1)="Yes", ROW($A$2:$A$9)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$9))+1), ROWS($A$14:A14))),"")}`